# SQL - Find where Client has not scheduled

Tags: sql

sorry not great at sql, simply trying too..

I've got a list of client appointments, say 1000 booked between 1st March - 1st June.
I'm then to find who (out of the 1000) who has not booked after 1st June? (ie who has not come back again)

```
SELECT distinct  Appointment.StartTime,  Appointment.ClientId
FROM     Appointments 
WHERE  (Appointment.AccountId = '12345678')
ORDER BY Events.StartTime
```

The output should show the Appointment.StartTime as LastAppointment,  Appointment.ClientId

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tags.

Comment: no problem, done

Answer (score 1):

If you want people who have made appointments between Mar 1 and Jun 1 but none after that, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT a.ClientId
FROM Appointments a
WHERE a.StartTime >= '2020-03-01' 
GROUP BY a.ClientId
HAVING MAX(a.StartTime) < '2020-06-01';
```

This returns clients who had an appointment after Mar 1 but whose latest appointment is before June.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this works as a client who booked on 18-April-2020 and has booked on the 02-June-2020 is showing in the results, he should not show as he has an appointment, I just want to see people who have not booked again

Comment: @D-W . . . No, such a client should not show up because the maximum of the start date is after 2020-06-01.